# Getting the parent DIV ID of the clicked UL LI select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems my apparent attempts at mastering the jQuery language have failed me.

I am attempting to try and get the DIV id of the UL LI select box but my alert box comes back "undefined", thus I am looking for expert help.

Here is the markup and code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.select {
    background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right top;
    border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width: 180px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.select:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select ul li {
    display: none;
    padding: 1px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

    $(".select").click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul li').toggle();
    });

    $(".select ul li").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest('div.select').text($(this).html());

        //alert($(this).closest('div.select').attr("id"))
        //alert($(this).closest('[id]').attr('id'))
        //alert($(this).closest('div.select').attr('id'))

    });

}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="select" id="numbers">Select Box1
    <ul>
        <li>1234</li>
        <li>5678</li>
        <li>0123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="letters">Select Box2
    <ul>
        <li>abcd</li>
        <li>efgh</li>
        <li>ijkl</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="select" id="fruits">Select Box3
    <ul>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: jQuery is a framework btw, please don't ever forget that.. Javascript is much faster by itself. ---- `element.parentElement` btw

Comment: Taplar is right, here is a working version of what it looks like you want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrjdvV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.text($(this).html()` this line messes with the DOM, and cause problems with traversal. I advice you uses other ways to accomplish the text change. Like

`$(this).closest("div").contents().first().replaceWith($(this).text());`

```js
$(".select ul li").click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest("div").contents().first().replaceWith($(this).text());
  var id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
  alert(id);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select" id="numbers">Select Box1
    <ul>
        <li>1234</li>
        <li>5678</li>
        <li>0123</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".select ul li").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('div.select').text($(this).html());

    //alert($(this).closest('div.select').attr("id"))
    //alert($(this).closest('[id]').attr('id'))
    //alert($(this).closest('div.select').attr('id'))

});
```

Ok, what I'm 99% sure is happening is due to you detaching the element.  Your setting the text() of the div.select, which is the parent of your select.  That is effectively removing the li element you clicked as a child.  So later when you try to do a closest it will not return anything as it's no longer a child.  You will most likely need to store that information before you change the text so you have the value without having to look it up afterwards.

```
$(".select ul li").click(function(e) {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('div.select');
    $parent.text($(this).html());
    alert($parent.attr('id'));
});
```